# How to prevent jungled absolute positioning in zooming?

Tags: css, position

I have read here in stackover flow and elsewhere that if we have a parent div with `relative` position, the child tags with `absolute` position will not relocate when zooming. But in my following example, it does not obey this rule.

> In the main file, I have `<img>` tags instead of div with ids img1 to
>   img3

Any advice will be appreciated.

```css
#container {
  position: relative;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  border: 3px solid green;
}
#img1 {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: red;
  left: 25%;
}
#img2 {
  position: absolute;
  width: 20px;
  height: 100px;
  background: blue;
  left: 30%;
}
#img3 {
  position: absolute;
  width: 20px;
  height: 100px;
  background: yellow;
  left: 60%;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="img1"></div>
  <div id="img2"></div>
  <div id="img3"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Absolute positioning is a **very** poor method of laying out webpages. It is extremely inflexible and there are much better and more responsive options. Check out [**LearnLayout.com**](http://learnlayout.com/)

Comment: @Paulie_D - I know we should refrain from absolute position. But, what should I do when I have 3 images that two of them lay over the third one?